# Sending only one sheet or active sheet as pdf via email

Tags: javascript, email, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello I have been trying to write my first script to send just one of the sheet from one of my google document but everytime I end up sending all the sheets instead. The document has a main page daily where i have the list of emails and then 7 sheets called monday, tuesday, etc

This is the code i use - can you help?

```
function emailActivesheetAsPDF() {
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  DriveApp.getFiles();

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_3VpJaFliJVYt1JL3cLSKw2ftsmsLeDjznHJ66-wq9w/edit");

  const value = ss.getSheetByName("Daily").getRange("B5").getValue();
  const email = value.toString();

  const subject = 'Yesterday Handover';

  const body = "Please find attached yesterday handover";

  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_3VpJaFliJVYt1JL3cLSKw2ftsmsLeDjznHJ66-wq9w/export?';

  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
    '&size=legal'
    '&portrait=true'
    '&fitw=false'
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false'
    '&fzr=false'
    '&gid=1263775066';
 
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: "Handover" + ".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation / Issue:

- You forgot to concatenate the options in the `exportOptions` variable and therefore `exportOptions` gets only the value of `&size=legal` and ignores the rest of the parameters including `gid` which you specify the sheet id. One solution is to concatenate the options via `+`.
- I also improved your code to make it more flexible. For example, instead of defining a sheet by its `gid` in the code, you can define it by its name in the variable `sheetToPrint` and then `GAS` will get its `gid` and use it as an export option for the pdf.

### Solution:

```
function emailActivesheetAsPDF() {
  const sheetToPrint = "Daily"; // name of the sheet to print
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_3VpJaFliJVYt1JL3cLSKw2ftsmsLeDjznHJ66-wq9w/edit");
  const ssID = ss.getId();
  const email = ss.getSheetByName("Daily").getRange("B5").getValue();
  const subject = 'Yesterday Handover';
  const body = "Please find attached yesterday handover";
  const shID = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToPrint).getSheetId();
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=pdf&id="+ssID;
  const exportOptions =
    '&size=legal'+
    '&portrait=true'+
    '&fitw=false'+
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'+
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false'+
    '&fzr=false'+
    '&gid='+shID; 
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: "Handover" + ".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    });
}
```

Comment: This is awesome - thank you. Is there a way to ensure that the PDF get sent to fit one page, at the moment it goes over 3 pages. Sorry very new at this :) Thank you

Comment: I figure it out. 
I had to change ‘&fitw=false to ‘&fitw=true  thank your for your help.

Comment: HI Mario - he did not work at the end as I have 7 different tabs and I would like to send one different every day - but I tried to create the 7 different scripts for each tab so that I can run on each day but it keeps sending the same one even though I change the sheet name... Can you suggest what I could do, please? thank you

Comment: Just curious do you have a reference for this method or did you figure this out yourself? I've never seen attachments with an object like that and I'd like to learn more about fetchapp and using it to convert files.  I've only seen a few references on github and SO but I can't locate any references in the documentation.  Thanks.  Sorry to bother you.

Comment: @Cooper unfortunately I don't have an official reference and I don't think it exists. I also found a GitHub source with all the options you can choose.

Comment: That's okay.  I was just curious to learn more.  I've seen that github reference too.  I'm curious how the first guy figured it out.