# Google Apps Script: Send PDF instead of .zip file in email

Tags: email, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have this code that generates a PDF file from a Google Spreadsheet and sends it as an email attachment. The issue is that it zips the file with `const zipBlob = Utilities.zip(blobs).setName('${ss.getName()}.zip');`.

I want to change it so that the attached file is a PDF and not a .zip file.

```
/* Send Spreadsheet in an email as PDF, automatically */
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  // Send the PDF of the spreadsheet to this email address
  const email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Árajánlat - EKOL Hungary').getRange('E3').getValue().toString();

  // Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
  // Or use SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("<>");
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Subject of email message
  const subject = `EKOL Hungary - ${ss.getName()}`;

  // Email Body can  be HTML too with your logo image - see ctrlq.org/html-mail
  const body = "Ide majd kell valami szöveg";

  // Base URL
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?'.replace('SS_ID', ss.getId());

  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    '&size=A4' + // paper size legal / letter / A4
    '&portrait=true' + // orientation, false for landscape
    '&fitw=true&source=labnol' + // fit to page width, false for actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=false' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid='; // the sheet's Id

  const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();

  // make an empty array to hold your fetched blobs
  const blobs = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i += 1) {
    // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + exportOptions + sheets[i].getSheetId(), {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });

    // convert the response to a blob and store in our array
    blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName(`${sheets[i].getName()}.pdf`);
  }

  // create new blob that is a zip file containing our blob array
  const zipBlob = Utilities.zip(blobs).setName(`${ss.getName()}.zip`);

  // Define the scope
  Logger.log(`Storage Space used: ${DriveApp.getStorageUsed()}`);

  // If allowed to send emails, send the email with the PDF attachment
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0)
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [zipBlob]
    });
}
```

I have also tried it this way, but it sends a corrupted PDF.

```
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  const sheetToPrint = "Árajánlat - EKOL Hungary"; // name of the sheet to print
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XTJF_-qYFvE4IVkA77YsOg3yfO_PX46z8z0_AtYg_Go/edit#gid=0");
  const ssID = ss.getId();
  const email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Árajánlat - EKOL Hungary').getRange('E3').getValue().toString();
  const subject = `EKOL Hungary - ${ss.getName()}`;
  const body = "Kicsit szépítettem rajta. Viszont, ide majd kéne valami szöveg. Mi legyen?";
  const shID = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToPrint).getSheetId();
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?'.replace('SS_ID', ss.getId());
  const exportOptions =
    '&size=A4'+
    '&portrait=true'+
    '&fitw=true'+
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'+
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false'+
    '&fzr=false'+
    '&gid='+shID; 
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: `EKOL Hungary - Árajánlat` + ".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    });
}
```

I would really appreciate any help you could give me as I am new to coding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending only one sheet or active sheet as pdf via email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65756215/sending-only-one-sheet-or-active-sheet-as-pdf-via-email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tries, the code below has done the trick.

```js
// Generate a PDF file from a Google spreadsheet and send it to a specified email address
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  const sheetToPrint = "Árajánlat - EKOL Hungary"; // name of the sheet to print
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // the sheets to use
  const email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Árajánlat - EKOL Hungary').getRange('E3').getValue().toString(); // grab the email address from the specified cell 
  const subject = `EKOL Hungary - ${ss.getName()}`; // the subject of the email
  const body = "Kicsit szépítettem rajta. Viszont, ide majd kéne valami szöveg. Mi legyen?"; // body of the email
  const shID = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToPrint).getSheetId(); // the ID of the sheet
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?'.replace('SS_ID', ss.getId()); // url of the spreadsheet
  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    '&size=A4'+ // size of the PDF (legal / A4 / letter)
    '&portrait=true'+ // orientation of the PDF (false for landscape)
    '&fitw=true'+ // fit to page width (false for actual size)
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'+ // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false'+ // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=false'+ // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid='+shID; // the sheet's Id
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  // generate the PDF file
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
  // send the email to the specified address with the specified body text and attached PDF file
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: `EKOL Hungary - ${ss.getName()}` + ".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    });
}
```

Comment: Didn't you want to add the full spreadsheet (all sheets) to your PDF? This will only add one sheet.

Comment: I only need one sheet to be exported, but the entire spreadsheet is just one sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `UrlFetchApp`, go for `ss.getAs('application/pdf')` ([See here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getascontenttype))

```
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  // Send the PDF of the spreadsheet to this email address
  var email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Árajánlat - EKOL Hungary').getRange('E3').getValue().toString();

  // Get the currently active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Subject of email message
  const subject = `EKOL Hungary - ${ss.getName()}`;

  // Get blob
  var blob = ss.getAs('application/pdf');

  // Send email
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
    htmlBody: body,
    attachments: [blob]
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it works well in only sending a PDF. Although, this way I can't add the exportOptions to remove the gridlines and format the PDF to A4 size. Do you have any suggestions on how to do both?