# Trigger based email send on google sheets giving some random results i dont understand

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I have been trying to make a script that will send email of a range of cells over email. While the sending email part works perfectly, when i add time based trigger to it, its sending out a random email i dont understand.

I am trying to send out a range of cells in my sheet that gets updated live to my boss automatically at 9:30Am everyday.

```
 function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var recipient = 'aaaabalamurali1996@gmail.com'
  var subject = 'NRV Tracker'
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy")
  var schedRange = sheet.getRange("A1:Y6"); 
  //var schedRange = sheet.getRange(Col == 3 && compare == date);

  
  var body = '<div style="text-align:center;display: inline-block;font-family: arial,sans,sans-serif">'
  body += '<H1>'+ 'NRV Tracker ' +'</H1>';
  body += '<H2>'
  body += getHtmlTable(schedRange);//change this line
  body += '</div>';
  debugger;

  recipient = 'abc@abc.com';  // For debugging, send only to self
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, "Requires HTML", {htmlBody:body})

  var ts = ss.getSheetByName("D-1 Day");
  var srange = sheet.getRange("A1:Y6");
  var trange = ts.getRange("A1:Y6");
  srange.copyTo(trange, {contentsOnly: true});
}


function getHtmlTable(range){
  var ss = range.getSheet().getParent();
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  startRow = range.getRow();
  startCol = range.getColumn();
  lastRow = range.getLastRow();
  lastCol = range.getLastColumn();

  // Read table contents
  var data = range.getValues();

  // Get css style attributes from range
  var fontColors = range.getFontColors();
  var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
  var fontFamilies = range.getFontFamilies();
  var fontSizes = range.getFontSizes();
  var fontLines = range.getFontLines();
  var fontWeights = range.getFontWeights();
  var horizontalAlignments = range.getHorizontalAlignments();
  var verticalAlignments = range.getVerticalAlignments();

 
  var colWidths = [];
  for (var col=startCol; col<=lastCol; col++) { 
    colWidths.push(sheet.getColumnWidth(col));
  }

 
  var rowHeights = [];
  for (var row=startRow; row<=lastRow; row++) { 
    rowHeights.push(sheet.getRowHeight(row));
  }

 
  var tableFormat = 'style="font-size: 10px; border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;text-align:center" border = 1 cellpadding = 1';
  var html = ['<table '+tableFormat+'>'];

  // Column widths appear outside of table rows
  for (col=0;col<colWidths.length;col++) {
    html.push('<col width="'+colWidths[col]+'">')
  }

 
  for (row=0;row<data.length;row++) {
    html.push('<tr height="'+rowHeights[row]+'">');
    for (col=0;col<data[row].length;col++) {
      // Get formatted data
      var cellText = data[row][col];
      if (cellText instanceof Date) {
        cellText = Utilities.formatDate(
                     cellText,
                     ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),
                     'M/d');
      }
      var style = 'style="'
                + 'color: ' + fontColors[row][col]+'; '
                + 'font-family: ' + fontFamilies[row][col]+'; '
                + 'font-size: ' + fontSizes[row][col]+'; '
                + 'font-weight: ' + fontWeights[row][col]+'; '
                + 'background-color: ' + backgrounds[row][col]+'; '
                + 'text-align: ' + horizontalAlignments[row][col]+'; '
                + 'vertical-align: ' + verticalAlignments[row][col]+'; '
                +'"';
      html.push('<td ' + style + '>'
                +cellText
                +'</td>');
    }
    html.push('</tr>');
  }
  html.push('</table>');

  return html.join('');
}
```

When i use the trigger i am getting this email.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9pGv.png)

Comment: You should pass your html table through HtmlService

Comment: How can i do that? Im new to this, if you can elaborate it will be great

Comment: I think maybe `body += HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(getHtmlTable(schedRange));` I put a comment next to the line to change in your code.

Comment: Hey, i have tried your edit. I am getting this in email.

Comment: https://imgur.com/wkPqs80 - I  am receiving this email

Answer (score 1):

Try referencing the range of cells that you wish to send to a new sheet and use the code below to send that sheet as a PDF. It is very easy to implement.

```js
// Generate a PDF file from a Google spreadsheet and send it to a specified email address
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  const sheetToPrint = "SPREADSHEET NAME"; // name of the sheet to print
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // the sheets to use
  const email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SHEET NAME').getRange('E3').getValue().toString(); // grab the email address from the specified cell 
  const subject = `SUBJECT - ${ss.getName()}`; // the subject of the email
  const body = "BODY"; // body of the email
  const shID = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToPrint).getSheetId(); // the ID of the sheet
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?'.replace('SS_ID', ss.getId()); // url of the spreadsheet
  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    '&size=A4'+ // size of the PDF (legal / A4 / letter)
    '&portrait=true'+ // orientation of the PDF (false for landscape)
    '&fitw=true'+ // fit to page width (false for actual size)
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'+ // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false'+ // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=false'+ // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid='+shID; // the sheet's Id
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  // generate the PDF file
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
  // send the email to the specified address with the specified body text and attached PDF file
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: `FILE NAME - ${ss.getName()}` + ".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    });
}
```

All you have to do is change the `SPREADSHEET NAME`, `SHEET NAME`, `SUBJECT`, `BODY`, and `FILE NAME`. Changing around the `ExportOptions` could also potentially help you.

Once you have this implemented, just set up a trigger for it to run every morning at 9AM.

If you have any questions, do not hesitate to contact me.

Comment: You were missing a single quote in email declaration. Hope you don't mind me changing it.

Comment: By the way I've been looking for where in the documentation this is explained because I'd like to understand it better but it only seems to exist here and there in github and on SO.

Comment: @Cooper You have a good eye! Thank you for the edit.

Comment: @Cooper What have you been looking for? I don't quite understand your second comment.

Comment: I've not seen attachments used with an object like that before. Was just curious where learned that.

Comment: The other thing is that I'd like to learn more about using fetchApp to convert files.  Sorry to barrage you with questions. And I'm just looking for a reference to read.

Comment: @Cooper No worries, I'm happy to help if I can. Although, I'm not entirely sure where I learned this. It was a bit of a patchwork project. What I can tell you though, is that I really like (and prefer) the fetchApp method because it gives you a lot of easy to use options for all kinds of conversions (xlsx, pdf, csv, and so on) and of course, the exportOptions. There's a little more info on it in a previous thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65835191/google-apps-script-send-pdf-instead-of-zip-file-in-email).